# AnyEvent stopped attempting to make connections after certain point

Tags: perl, anyevent

Created a script to test against a server (it's capable of over 100K concurrent TCP sockets). Affter it reaches 65536, the client stopped attempting to set up connections.  Wonder why.

```
use AnyEvent;
use EV;
use AnyEvent::Handle;
use IO::Socket::UNIX;
use Time::HiRes qw( gettimeofday );
use Data::Dumper;
my $count = 0;
my @hds = ();
my $cv = AnyEvent->condvar;
my $ips = ["192.168.1.11", "192.168.1.12","192.168.1.13","192.168.1.14"];
my $i;
my $j = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i++) {
    kickoff();
}
$cv->recv;

sub kickoff {
    my $hdl = new AnyEvent::Handle
      connect => ["192.168.1.1", 80],
      on_error => sub {
         my ($hdl, $fatal, $msg) = @_;
         print "error when count=$count, $!\n";
         $hdl->destroy;
         $cv->send;
      },
        on_connect => sub {
            $count ++;
            if ($count > 65000) {
                print "$count\n";
            } elsif (($count % 1000) == 0) {
                print "$count\n";
            }
            if ($count >= 100000) { return; }
            kickoff();

        },
        on_prepare => sub {
            my $hdl = shift;
            #print Dumper($hd); exit;
            mybind($hdl->{fh}, $ips->[$j%4]);
            $j ++;
        },
        on_read => ::handleData;
     push @hds, $hdl;
}

sub getTS {
    my ($seconds, $microseconds) = gettimeofday;
    return $seconds + (0.0+ $microseconds)/1000000.0;
}

sub mybind {
    my ($sock, $ip) = @_;
    my $local_host=inet_aton($ip) or return undef;
    my $local = sockaddr_in(0, $local_host);
    bind($sock,$local) or print 'Couldn\'t bind to local\n';

}
```

For the record, I ran it as root on Ubuntu 14.04 (linux 3.19.0) and `ulimit -a` shows 100000.

Any idea why?

**UPDATE1**

Some update based on the comments. Thanks guys.

- When I use only one IP, I can easily go to 27000 concurrent TCP connections. The port range (for each host) should allow 100,000 connections on 4 hosts.
- I have`fs.nr_open = 1048576` but don't have config for net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max
- The max number "65536" can mean many things: 1) max number of ports on a host 2) the number of numbers in a 2-byte short integer.  So it could be related. Wonder where I can redefine the limit or if it's possible to redefine it.
- When I reach the number 65536, it stopped attempting to create new connections.

Comment: Other sysctls that could break things are `fs.nr_open` (usually large enough though nowadays) and `net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max`. Setting `SO_REUSEADDR` on the socket might help, too.

Comment: Why are you calling `kickoff` recursively from within the `on_connect` subroutine as well as iteratively from the `for` loop?

Comment: I'm guessing it's to spread the load. It limits the number of connecting sockets to 1000

Comment: There are only 65536 TCP ports per address. Could be because of that?

Comment: What happens when you reach that number?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It's answered in the update1.